# Memory Leaks: Using NEW only once but many leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator

I am writing a memory leak finder in a project. But I not understand why i get a leak in another place.

```
__inline void Dbg_DebugMemLeaksToFile( const int iCrtFlags, const char * pszFileName ) {

          ... Create a file here ...

          _CrtSetDbgFlag( iCrtFlags );

          if ( hLogFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
              _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT,  _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG ); //| _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW );
              _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN,    _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );
              _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR,   _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG ); //| _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW );

              _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ASSERT,  hLogFile );
              _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_WARN,    hLogFile );
              _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ERROR,   hLogFile );
              }

          _CrtMemState memsnap;
          _CrtMemCheckpoint( &memsnap );

          _CrtCheckMemory();
          _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
          _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&memsnap);

          ///>
          if ( hLogFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
              CloseHandle( hLogFile );
        }
```

Now to use the code.

```
    int WINAPI _tWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, nCmdShow ) {
  //Test my memory leaker.
  DBG_ENABLE_CRT_DUMP_MEMORY_LEAKS_TO_FILE( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF, "CRT_DebugLeakReport.txt");
  char * Leak = new char[10];   <-- Make this leak.   
  return (0);
}
```

When run and open the file. I get this output...

```
> Detected memory leaks!
  Dumping objects ->
  (128) normal block at 0x00D20560, 10 bytes long.
   Data: <   > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
  Object dump complete.
```

This is okay and good! This is what it should do.

****BUT****

Before this leak report. i get this leak.

```
> Detected memory leaks!
    Dumping objects ->
    (158) normal block at 0x00D0FF58, 44 bytes long.
    Data: < X   X   X       > 58 FF D0 00 58 FF D0 00 58 FF D0 00 01 01 CD CD
    (157) normal block at 0x00D20288, 8 bytes long.
    Data : < 2 ? > A4 32 3F 00 00 00 00 00
    (156) normal block at 0x00D0A3A0, 44 bytes long.
    Data : <                > A0 A3 D0 00 A0 A3 D0 00 A0 A3 D0 00 01 01 CD CD
    (155) normal block at 0x00D20640, 8 bytes long.
    Data : < p ? > 70 1C 3F 00 00 00 00 00
    (154) normal block at 0x00D20448, 8 bytes long.
    Data : < ? > A8 18 3F 00 00 00 00 00
    (153) normal block at 0x00D20330, 8 bytes long.
    Data : < ? > 98 18 3F 00 00 00 00 00
    Object dump complete.
    0 bytes in 0 Free Blocks.
    120 bytes in 6 Normal Blocks.
    21534 bytes in 160 CRT Blocks.
    0 bytes in 0 Ignore Blocks.
    0 bytes in 0 Client Blocks.
    Largest number used : 28572 bytes.
    Total allocations : 54107 bytes.
```

I do not understand why i get this leak when i only have "char * Leak = new char[10];" (I understand how and why i get this leak) but not the other leak. I do not think "Dbg_DebugMemLeaksToFile" is leaking because i am not using "new".

Can i get your help with my code and understand what i miss please??

**UPDATE**
Today i download VLD,[Visual Leak Detector](https://kinddragon.github.io/vld/)
so i
can check if my leak detector i am writing is working okay. VLD did find a leak because
of

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <crtdbg.h> 

//#pragma comment(lib, "vld.lib") <-- I test this with my memory leaker.
//#include "include/vld.h"


void Dbg_DebugMemLeaksToFile( const int iCrtFlags, const char * pszFileName ) {
   ... my code i post ...
}

 #define   DBG_ENABLE_CRT_DUMP_MEMORY_LEAKS_TO_FILE( x, y )     Dbg_DebugMemLeaksToFile( x, y );


int WINAPI _tWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow ) {

DBG_ENABLE_CRT_DUMP_MEMORY_LEAKS_TO_FILE(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF, "CRT_DebugLeakReport.txt");

char * Leak = new char[10]; <-- Make this leak.
return 0;
}
```

Both VLD and my code report this. But VLD dose not report the other leak i post.
So i try to think if something is wrong with my code. I understand i can have
false-positive. but then why dose my code report this but not
VLD?

Comment: You're asking us to explain why a memory leak detector that you have written (and not provided the source code for) is giving a false detection  of a memory leak?    That's a pretty tall order.  There are all sorts of possible explanations.   The obvious is that some code in your project that you haven't shown (or presumably considered) has a leak - which will be nasty if that is in your memory leak detector itself.   A number of Microsoft-specific function, like the ones you're using, may allocate resources - you need to read documentation carefully to confirm it that is the case.

Comment: One origin of false detection is that the detection happens **before** some (global) objects (such as `std::cout`) are destroyed.